# Hive count number of matching rows in another table

Tags: hive, presto

Table1:

```
| ID | Timestamp
| 1  | 1970
| 2  | 1971
```

Table2:

```
| Timestamp |
| 1970      |
| 1970      |
| 1970      |
| 1971      |
| 1971      |
```

How can I perform a query that joins the tables in such a way that I get:

```
| ID | Timestamp | Count
| 1  | 1970      | 3
| 2  | 1971      | 2
```

basically `join on timestamp` but only to get a count?

Answer (score 2):

```
select  t1.ID
       ,t1.`Timestamp`
       ,coalesce (t2.`Count`,0) as `Count`

from    Table1 t1

        left join  (select      `Timestamp`
                                ,count(*)    as `Count`
                    from        Table2
                    group by    `Timestamp`
                    ) t2

        on          t2.`Timestamp` = t1.`Timestamp`
```

---

```
+----+-----------+-------+
| id | timestamp | count |
+----+-----------+-------+
|  1 |      1970 |     3 |
|  2 |      1971 |     2 |
+----+-----------+-------+
```